# How to Cast List(Int) to Int without using for loop

Tags: scala

I'm Trying to cast Second Element of nested List(Int) `var element = List(List[String]())` to `Int`

```
  element :+= List("rules", "8")
```

I tried like `var value = element.tail().toString.toInt but it returns List(Int)`

also tried `var value =  element.tail().map(_.toString.toInt)` but no luck again `List(8)`

I want to convert the tail part of `List("8")` to Integer

I don't find any direct method to do so, So I tried like

```
for(convert <- element.tail){ var casted = convert.toInt }
```

What is the efficient way to convert the second element of a nested List(Int) to Int ?

Comment: What is the output you are expecting, one int value? If so `list.last.toInt` or `list(1).toInt`

Comment: Yeah, can you be more specific about the desired output here @Vignesh

Comment: @soote, its `list(1).toInt`

Comment: Thank you soote, its working now.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tail` method returns another `List` with all the elements except the first. That's why it doesn't work in your case. 
If you know that your list has exactly 2 elements, you can access the second either by `last` or `list(1)` and then call `toInt`, so in your case

```
element.last.toInt
```

or

```
element(1).toInt
```